# Stop a variable from printing out multiple times

Tags: java, user-interface

I have a GUI which is printing out the total cost of something but the total at the top of the GUI keeps re-printing the result instead of just changing the number (or double value).

here is the code (the section im talking about is the "output.insert"):

Comment: Where is `output` defined? What is its type? Why aren't you doing anything with `addByNbr` and where is `addByNbrUnits` defined? Who is calling `numberPurchase` and in what circumstances?

Comment: @RealSkeptic there i have added the other class file where it is defined etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
output.insert("total to pay: " + priceToPay+ "\n", 0);
```

Looks to me like that line of code is adding new text to the component.

Instead I would guess you should be using something like:

```
output.setText("total to pay: " + priceToPay+ "\n", 0);
```

Comment: that doesnt work because it only accepts a String and wont allow me to set that i want it on the top line (the 0 at the end). and it also removes my other outputs

Answer (score 0):

When you use `output.insert(something,0)` it's like appending at the beginning. It means that it adds the text at offset 0, pushing all the existing text after it.

If you want to replace the line rather than insert a new one before it, you should use `replaceRange` rather than `insert`. At least starting  from the second time around.

So suppose you add a field that checks if it's the first time or not:

```
private static boolean firstTimeShowingTotal = true;
```

Then you can change the `output.insert` line in your event handler to:

```
String totalToShow = "total to pay: " + priceToPay+ "\n";
if ( firstTimeShowingTotal ) {
    output.insert(totalToShow, 0);
    firstTimeShowingTotal = false;
} else {
    int endOfFirstLine = output.getLineEndOffset(0);
    output.replaceRange(totalToShow, 0, endOfFirstLine);
}
```

The `getLineEndOffset` will find the offset of the end of the first line in the text. The `replaceRange` call will replace the text from 0 to that offset with your new message.

---

Unrelated note: check your static fields. It's not a good idea to create an instance of a class if all the fields are static. I believe most of those fields should be instance fields rather than static.